# wget stuck on "HTTP request sent, awaiting response..." not timing out

Tags: linux, download, wget

I have wget set up to download pages from a site with the following parameters:

```
wget -r --level=400 --retry-connrefused --waitretry=2 --read-timeout=15 --timeout=15 -t 0 [ site ]
```

The timeout feature works correctly sometimes, but at others, it does not, and the program displays

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

and doesn't resolve, meaning the whole download process needs to be cancelled.

Is there a fix for this or some way to resume recursive downloading from the last page that it downloaded successfully, i.e. not downloading those pages already saved to the disk and instead just carrying on from where it was stopped?

I'm certain that this doesn't have to do with the internet connection as I'm able to visit each page in the web browser despite the fact that wget has halted on the HTTP request.

Comment: The message "HTTP request sent, awaiting response..." means that the DNS works fine, that the TCP connection was established and the request was sent. It's more likely that the problem is in the remote server that might be too busy. Questions: (1) Is the problem always with the same server? (2) If you try again later, does it work? (3) Can the problem be an HTTP request when the server only accepts HTTPS? (4) Is the site specified by name or IP address? (5) Is the URL very long?

Comment: I solved the problem; for some reason when I plugged my computer in to the ethernet after half a dozen failed attempts over WiFi it worked fine.

To answer your questions harrymc, I have only encountered this problem while trying to connect to one site with a URL which is 20 or so letters long, and the HTTPS connection is fine and is kept open as is the default. I suspect therefore that the problem originates within the WiFi connection itself.